# Youtube: Exceed quota error for newly created API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have enabled Youtube Data API an hour ago and  made a few requests and I am already getting the following error:

```
b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \\u003ca href=\\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\\"\\u003equota\\u003c/a\\u003e.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \\u003ca href=\\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\\"\\u003equota\\u003c/a\\u003e.",\n        "domain": "youtube.quota",\n        "reason": "quotaExceeded"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n'
```

When I go to dashboard I see the following:

[image]

and

[image]

and
[image]

Below is the code I am trying:

```
def upload_video(video_file, channel_id, youtube_object):
    try:
        # Define the video metadata
        request_body = {
            'snippet': {
                'title': 'TESTING BY ME',
                'description': 'Your video description',
                'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'],
                'categoryId': '22',  # Set the appropriate category ID
                'channelId': channel_id  # Set the channel ID
            },
            'status': {
                'privacyStatus': 'private'  # Set the privacy status of the video
            }
        }

        # Create a media upload object for the video file
        media = MediaFileUpload(video_file)

        # Execute the video insert request
        response = youtube_object.videos().insert(
            part='snippet,status',
            body=request_body,
            media_body=media
        ).execute()

        # Print the video ID of the uploaded video
        print('Video uploaded. Video ID:', response['id'])

    except HttpError as e:
        print('An HTTP error occurred:')
        print(e.content)

    except Exception as e:
        print('An error occurred:')
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the YT quota calculator, uploading videos is quite 'expensive'. Current 'cost' is 1,600 units. So it wouldn't take many uploads (around 7?) to exceed the daily 10,000 unit daily allowance.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost